# Php, "call to undefined function curl_init()" in browser BUT works fine on cmd

Tags: php, curl

I have a simple test code:

```
<?php
var_dump(curl_init());
echo '.';
```

if I run it on command line (Windows 10) I get the expected result:

**php.exe test.php**

> resource(4) of type (curl) .

very fine. But when Im running this file from browser (set to Apache rootdir).

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in

Im speachless. For legacy reasons, this is php 7.04 (on 7.2, 7.4, 8.1 everything is fine).
The php.ini does work. Of course "extension=php_curl.dll" is enabled. When I change something, for example "max_execution_time = 300", the `php_info();` also reinforcements me that these settings are taken into account.
However, the strange thing is what php_info() is saying:

> cURL  Sterling Hughes

nothing more for curl!

EDIT:

I tried the same with "extension=php_gd2.dll" and it does work if I remove/readd it, phpinfo shows that correctly!

Comment: Make sure you've enabled the curl extension. The cli might be using a different php.ini than the handler you've chosen for the domain

Comment: It might not necessarily be "the" php.ini - CLI, and how PHP is actually embedded into the web server, might use _different_ configurations. Have you verified via the phpinfo output, that that is not the case?

Comment: Some configs have a seperate `php.ini` for the CLI and the web server. So write a quick web page with just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then read the `Loaded Configuration File` from the first page of that output, to see what `php.ini` is actually being used by the server

Comment: the "Loaded Configuration File" also shows the correct php.ini file. But like I said, chaning "max_execution_time = 300" also shown as correct.

Comment: Are you using a WAMPServer/XAMPP or did you install PHP and Apache all yourself

Comment: `cURL Sterling Hughes` is in the Authors section. Do you have a proper `cURL` section in the `phpinfo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the php folder is not in your system PATH (not user), Apache doesn't know where to search dlls. The easiest way is adding php folder to PATH.

If you doesn't want to do that, you probably need set `extension_dir` to the full path of your extension folder in `php.ini`. for example:

```
extension_dir = "D:\Program Files\php-7.04-ts\ext"
```

[cURL extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php) needs openssl to work. <s>and you can also find these dlls in php folder, just copy them to Windows or system32 folder.</s> According to RiggsFolly's comment you can copy these required dlls to `Apache\bin` folder.

- libssl-1_1-x64.dll /  libeay32.dll
- libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll / ssleay32.dll
- libssh2.dll

Comment: this set like that, and still no joy :(

Comment: yes, that was the case... I had to copy the "libeay32.dll", "libssh2.dll", "ssleay32.dll" files

Comment: **DONT** copy then to the windows or system32 folder. Instead copy then to the Apache/bin folder, placed in the windows folder they will get forgotten about and will forever give you problems when you change versions of PHP/Apache

Comment: If you still have `libeay32.dll", "ssleay32.dll"` then your using an old and insecure version of Apache/PHP/openssl

Comment: @RiggsFolly I use apache 2.4, libcrypto and libssl-1_1 are already in the bin folder with a newer version, so only libssh2.dll needs to be copied.